# Quaternion from global space to local space

Tags: coordinate-systems, quaternions

I've searched but have not found a response for this question specifically.

I have a smartphone with a sensor that gives me a quaternion representing its absolute rotation relatively to the following axis:

X - tangent to Earth, pointing to East;
Y - tangent to Earth, pointing to the North;
Z = X cross Y, orthogonal to Earth, pointing upwards.

When the smartphone screen is parallel to the ground plane and aligned to the East, the sensor reads Q = 1 + 0i + 0j + 0k.

I know that, for any 2 quaternions Q and R, the offset rotation from Q to R, i.e., D such that R = D * Q, would be R * Q^-1.

Now, I'd like to take a reference frame (calibration) and, for any quaternion Q, obtain a new quaternion Q' that represents offset rotation from the calibration to the current rotation, but using the device itself as reference, i.e.:

X' - tangent to the device screen, pointing right of the device;
Y' - tangent to the device screen, pointing up of the device;
Z' = X' cross Y', orthogonal to the screen, pointing out from it.

How can I do that? Please, be gentle with me, I'm not a mathematician, just a poor programmer. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you realize that $X'\times Y'$ points *out* of the screen (if you are being consistent with your earlier description of $X,Y,Z$)  You *can* switch it to a left-handed coordinate system, but there would no longer be a *rotation* that does that. You would need a reflection too.

Comment: You're right, it would be out of the screen, not towards it.

Comment: In general it is frowned upon to modify the question to make answers obsolete. I don't mind that much, though, in this case. Just bear it in mind. What does "take a reference frame" mean?

Comment: The newest revision has really confused the discussion: are you talking about three frames of reference now?

Comment: Sorry about that :-(. For the frame, I'll store an absolute rotation in the original coordinate system at calibration time, then use it as base rotation for any subsequent read of the sensor. So I want the offset rotation relative to this base rotation, but at phone coordinates.

Comment: It sounds like the 'earth' coordinates never come into play at all. You are just want the transformation from 'calibration' coordinates into 'phone' coordinates. I don't see how the strategy would be any different than the one I outlined. Maybe you can provide a drawing with the earth frame, the initial frame, and then a particular orientation of your camera.

Comment: I probably either do not understand quaternions enough or do not understand my own doubt. I've tried this: read the absolute rotation and apply the offset rotation, relative to the reference frame, to a virtual avatar that is aligned to the X axis. If the sensor in the real world is aligned with the East, the transformation works, otherwise it gets weird. I want to calibrate the sensor once and get the rotation relative to this initial rotation. However, I need it to be in phone coordinates, otherwise the sensor actual orientation on the planet changes the measurements, as I explained.

Comment: Speaking for myself, what confuses me most is your description of coordinates and what you need. I don't see any problems stemming from lack of understanding of quaternions.

Comment: So I've described how to transform 'earth' coordinates to 'phone' coordinates, and the same strategy applies if you initialize your phone to 'init' coordinates and then want to transform to 'phone' coordinates. I think you are asking about this latter transformation in your latest version. What does the rotation between 'earth' and 'init' have to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate your 'earth' coordinates into 'phone' coordinates, you would just have to rotate the $X,Y$ plane counterclockwise by $\theta$ radians where $\theta$ is the angle (counterclockwise) from $X$ to $X'$.

So, you'd need a quaternion that looks like $q=\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})+\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})k$.

Comment: I have actually figured out that I need the relative rotation from a reference frame, I will update the question to clarify that.